# how to create a template framework for joomla cms like T3?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

How do i create a template framework for joomla cms like T3, what's the best way to start?, i'm not asking you to do my homework, i just need you to guide me what things i should consider in my mind and which way will be the best for creating a template framework for joomla CMS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to your question other than it depends. What are you trying to accomplish? Who is the target user? Do you plan to use a javascript library? Do you plan to use Mootools like the core? Before you can even begin a framework, you first need to determine what you want it to do. In many cases a framework is total overkill and needless overhead for a user than knows how to achieve what the framework does without the additional code.